# Append html to bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, append, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to load an image from a php foreach loop into a bootstrap modal using data- attribute but nothing showing in target div - here's my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $( ".subscribe" ).on( "click", function() {
  var imgURL = $( this ).attr( "data-img-url" );
  console.log(imgURL);
});


$( "#subscribeModal" ).on('shown', function(){
  $('#sub_img').append('<img src="'+imgURL+'" />');
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: your var  imgURL;  is a local variable

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 issues. First is the `imgURL` parameter mentioned elsewhere. Second, the name of the event to bind to should be `shown.bs.modal`. The documentation on the [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) says:

> **show.bs.modal** This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

```
$( "#subscribeModal" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $('#sub_img').append('<img src="'+imgURL+'" />');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `imgURL` is local to the click handler, so it won't be accessible inside the `shown` handler. Declare the variable in a shared scope of both those functions to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgURL;
    $(".subscribe").on("click", function () {
        imgURL = $(this).attr("data-img-url");
        console.log(imgURL);
    });


    $("#subscribeModal").on('shown', function () {
        $('#sub_img').append('<img src="' + imgURL + '" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1199795 then it is time to provide full example. You can either miss some elements, or events are triggered in not-you-suppose order, or `shown` is incorrect event.

Comment: thx your solution worked, event name was wrong as pointed out below. thx both